# Hit the api on scroll dropdown select options, Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, select, dropdown

I need to hit api while scrolling the dropdown select options,initially i am getting 20 records in dropdown, i want to load more records while scrolling options down to the list.

Comment: Please provide some code and a deeper behavior of your problem, there is no way to help you with 2 short lines of unclear explanation.

Comment: There is a list of data having 20 records displaying in dropdown, i want to load next records from the server on scroll and reach at the bottom.

Comment: Once again: provide **some code** and a **deeper behavior** of your problem.